# socket doesn't exist; Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, lamp

I know the problem isn't new. But I have tried lots of thing. What I couldn't figure out is, socket wasn't available since I downloaded mysql.

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf
```

None of the above [files](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067116) are available. I had downloaded mysql-server at first. As it wasn't working I downloaded MariaDB. Still not working. What I can do with MySql is `enable`, `restart` (but not start) and `version check`. I can't find out anything else I could do.

tried all the following links and more. [1](https://serverfault.com/q/523155/989920), [2](https://serverfault.com/a/170217/989920), [3](https://serverfault.com/a/400883/989920)

```
$-mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
```

I get the following message if I execute `systemctl status mysql`.

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-10-25 20:28:52 +06; 12min ago
    Process: 23398 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 4ms

অক্টোবর 25 20:28:52 istiak-PASSION-BX-PRO systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
অক্টোবর 25 20:28:52 istiak-PASSION-BX-PRO systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
অক্টোবর 25 20:28:52 istiak-PASSION-BX-PRO systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
অক্টোবর 25 20:28:52 istiak-PASSION-BX-PRO systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
অক্টোবর 25 20:28:52 istiak-PASSION-BX-PRO systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I tried reinstalling `mysql-server` still same issue. FYI, I had installed them with lampp-server also but I can't find lampp folder/file also.

```
/etc/mysql$ ls
mariadb.conf.d  mysql.conf.d
```

`mariadb.conf.d` has `50-client.cnf.dpkg-new  50-mysql-clients.cnf.dpkg-new  60-galera.cnf.dpkg-new` and `mysql.conf.d` is empty.

```
$ locate mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

but

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d$ cat mysql.cnf
cat: mysql.cnf: No such file or directory
```

```
$ cat /var/log/mysql/error.log
2022-10-25T07:48:52.228831Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) initializing of server in progress as process 28839
2022-10-25T07:48:52.302162Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-25T07:49:09.874747Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-10-25T07:50:06.236820Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2022-10-25T07:51:08.281884Z 6 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2022-10-25T07:51:38.826105Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 28898
2022-10-25T07:51:39.554318Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-25T07:51:41.855856Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-10-25T07:51:46.281301Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-10-25T07:51:46.281340Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-10-25T07:51:46.333725Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-10-25T07:51:46.379072Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-10-25T07:51:46.379082Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.AGSySmwCxw/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2022-10-25T07:51:46.647513Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2022-10-25T07:51:51.615872Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-10-25T07:51:52.202270Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 28983
2022-10-25T07:51:52.209027Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-25T07:51:54.558257Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-10-25T07:51:57.829629Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-10-25T07:51:57.829657Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-10-25T07:51:57.889261Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-10-25T07:51:58.081569Z 7 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2022-10-25T07:51:58.085366Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-10-25T07:52:01.902843Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-10-25T07:52:03.914295Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 29105
2022-10-25T07:52:04.447669Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-25T07:52:06.721404Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-10-25T07:52:10.519027Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-10-25T07:52:10.519055Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-10-25T07:52:10.536998Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-10-25T07:52:10.537077Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2022-10-25T08:14:19.130322Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 1057
2022-10-25T08:14:20.074090Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-25T08:14:33.814659Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-10-25T08:14:37.852644Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2022-10-25T08:14:37.862734Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2022-10-25T08:14:38.881437Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-10-25T08:14:38.881467Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-10-25T08:14:39.184636Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-10-25T08:14:39.184667Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2022-10-25T08:27:57.845047Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
2022-10-25T08:27:59.876899Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

Comment: I can't see any issue in error.log. All I can think is, I don't have socket and no file of configuring mysql.

Comment: I am facing the problem whole day, still couldn't solve. Your little help will save my another day. For the shitty problem, I dared to change OS. But my RAM isn't that good enough to use Android-Studio in WIndows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking longer than usual, I realized the MySQL is completely broken in my system. Even while removing MySQL, there's always some files left behind. SO I directly installed a new distribution again. Again downloaded Xampp from official page.

```
$cd Downloads
$sudo chmod +x xampp.run
$sudo ./xampp.run
```

Then a dialog box (installation) appear, after completing the installation, I got a Lampp folder in /opt. And a lampp executable file /opt/lampp/lampp

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./lampp start
```

If lampp isn't executable then run

```
sudo chmod +x lampp
```